# Proving that the linear mapping $f: P(x,\Bbb R) \to P(x,\Bbb R)$, which maps the polynomial $p(x)$ to the polynomial $p(x-1)$, is the isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> **My example**: Prove that the linear mapping $f: P(x,\Bbb R) \to  P(x,\Bbb R)$, which maps the polynomial $p(x)$ to the polynomial
>   $p(x-1)$, is the isomorphism.

**My solution**: So we have $p(x)\to p(x-1)$ and we can write it as

$a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 +...+a_nx^n \to a_0 + a_1(x-1) + a_2(x-1)^2 +...+a_n(x-1)^n $

The basis of $p(x)$ is $\{1,x,x^2,...\}$ and the basis of $p(x-1)$ is $\{1,x-1,(x-1)^2,...\}$ which is the basis of the image.

- Both bases are infinite so the vector spaces of our given polynomials are also infinite.

The polynomial itself cannot be infinite, it has some degree, for example $n$ and we can see that $1$ is mapped to $1$, $x \to (x-1)$,..., $x^n \to (x-1)^n$, so our given linear transformation is injective.

$f: P(x,\Bbb R) \to  P(x,\Bbb R)$ is obviously an endomorphism.

- In my book is written that if some linear mapping is the endomorphism and an monomorphism (injective) it must be also an epimorphism (surjective) and the isomorphism is both the monomorphism and the epimorphism, but for the finite vector spaces, so what about this "infinite" example?

I think it's obvious that my given mapping is isomorphism (it's actually an automorphism), but is there any more proper way to prove it?

Comment: Bases really aren't as useful for proving theorems about infinite dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Lambda: P(x,\Bbb R)\to P(x,\Bbb R)$ be given by $(\Lambda p)(x) = p(x-1)$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

Then you need to prove $2$ things:

1. $\Lambda$ is linear.
2. $\Lambda$ is invertible.

Hints:

1. You just need to show $$(\Lambda (p_1 + kp_2))(x) = \cdots = (\Lambda p_1)(x) + k(\Lambda p_2)(x)$$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.  Use the definition of the sum and multiple of functions.
2. Intuitively, it's clear that the inverse $\Lambda^{-1}:P(x,\Bbb R) \to P(x,\Bbb R)$ is the function given by $(\Lambda^{-1}p)(x) = p(x+1)$.  Prove it.

Comment: I am thinking now how to prove that part with the inverse mapping, the existence. Should I show it's linear again? I don't see a big difference betweeen $p(x-1)$ and $p(x+1)$ (by the intuition, not numerically).

Comment: The inverse of a linear map will always be linear.  Just prove that $\Lambda^{-1}$ *is* the inverse of $\Lambda$ using the definition of inverse functions.

Comment: Ok, I am going to search it, thank you.

Comment: The definition is $\Lambda^{-1}$ is the inverse of $\Lambda$ if $\Lambda\Lambda^{-1} = I$ and $\Lambda^{-1}\Lambda = I$ where $I$ is the identity transformation.  It should be a really short proof.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to say is that the map which maps every $p(x)$ to $p(x-1)$ is linear (obvious, since $(p+q)(x-1) = (p(x-1) + q(x-1)),$) and invertible, the inverse being $p(x) \to p(x+1).$

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't thinking about that this way.